# = and LIKE operator in a sql command

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

So i have these two query in my access VBA code. The When I replace `like` with `=` i end up retrieving no records. the like works perfectly with out a hitch but I can't use it because sometimes it'll pull up the wrong data. What am I doing wrong with the = operator?

```
Set rsStepCalendar = db.OpenRecordset("Select * from tblStepCalendar " & _
                                      "Where (groupNr = '*" & txtGroupNum.Value & "*' ) " & _
                                      "AND (Cancel = False)", dbOpenDynaset)
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("Select * from tblContacts " & _
                          "Where (groupNum = '*" & txtGroupNum.Value & "*' ) " & _
                          "AND (canceledContact = False)", dbOpenDynaset)
```

Comment: The = comparison (think of it as _equal_) does not honor wildcards (* <- Wildcard). It looks for exact matches!

Comment: Right! that's what i'm assuming txtGroupNum.Value and txtGroupNum.Value hold values from strictly the database. So I don't understand why I get no results when I use them to find a record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`groupNum = '*" & txtGroupNum.Value & "*'`

Is looking for the value surrounded by asterisk characters which only have symbolic meaning as "anything" when combined with `LIKE`.

For `=` use `groupNum = '" & txtGroupNum.Value & "'`

You should also escape any user input/use parametrized queries.